# "ClassNotFoundException:org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer" when trying to use Simple XML API

Tags: eclipse, servlets, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I'm using the Simple XML API to serialize and deserialize XML data being sent from an Android app to a servlet. 
The deserialization works fine on the android app. But when the same code is used on the servlet I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlettest.ServletTest] in context with path [/test] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at servlettest.ServletTest.doPost(ServletTest.java:104)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The highlight being `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer`

I have made sure that the jar file has been imported in Eclipse. It has been checked mark under "Order and Export" tab of the "Properties" window.

Here is the code which works fine on Android but fails on the servlet:

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
            File source = new File("/home/kk/workspace/testfile.xml");

            Reg_info_xml parse_xml = serializer.read(Reg_info_xml.class, source);
            String name = parse_xml.getUser_name();
            System.out.print(name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class ins't in the server class path, so put your jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your project

Comment: No luck. 
I did place it in that folder but I still get the same error. I import it as an external jar, right?

Comment: Got it! Had to refresh the /lib directory in Eclipse to get it to detect the jar file. 
Thank you :)